# DIV positioning, Content always overflow

Tags: html, css

[image: My Problem]
[image: With margin-bottom]
With margin-bottom

```css
#txtmiddle {
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#midcontentimgright {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  max-width: 25%;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="middlewrapper">
  <div id="txtmiddle" class="content6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</div>
  <div id="txtmiddle" class="content7">Lorem ipsum <a id="mapa" href="map.htm">KARTE</a>
    <img src="/MapAusschnitt.png" id="midcontentimgright" class="4">
  </div>
  <div id="txtmiddle" class="content7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod WERDEN SIE</div>
</div>
```

its really hard for me to understand that positioning... i just dont want any overflow, everything should be inside that div elements....

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to address here that might help you out.

Without a JSfiddle and the original image I can't tell you how much the margin needs to change, but it looks like your `img` tag's `margin-top` is too large. Otherwise, if you were looking for that space on the top of the image in the div, you should change the `height` of the CSS for `#txtmiddle`. By explicitly defining the `height` of the element in the CSS you can avoid a situation in which the `img` tag is not contained within the `div`.

Secondly, in your snippet you have 3 divs where `id="txtmiddle"`, perhaps this should be a class instead as ID tags should generally reference one unique object in the DOM, not multiple.  This change would be reflected in the CSS by altering the rule definition from `#txtmiddle`  to `.txtmiddle` and likewise getting rid of the `id` attributes on the div tags and placing them after the `content*` classes.

It might also be helpful to wrap the `img` tag within another div and set that div to a specific height.

Hope that gives you something.

Viel Glück!

Comment: Danke! ah, ok then i mixed up id and class, thanks for noticing! about the problem: my #txtmiddle is defined by min-height, but not with a height attribute.. i hoped the margin of inside elements will stretch the div (that's what i expected it to do...)

Comment: Using an the id for the `img` tag make the `margin-top` smaller than `10px` and you won't see the overlap problem.  Here's a JSFiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq5ebqx2/)

Comment: thanks, ok I see now what you mean.. when i remove the float attribute the div is sized dynamically with the inner margin - can I achieve that with having float-attribute?

Comment: Just add `overflow: auto;` to the containing div.  And you can keep the float as is. [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq5ebqx2/) Cheers